# Dynamically update figure with plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to update my plot every loop iteration. So I don't want to use `animation` I know there is a lot of examples in network, but on my PC it works only in debug mode. So common case look something like this

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


plt.ion() # set plot to animated

ydata = [0] * 50
ax1=plt.axes()

# make plot
line, = plt.plot(ydata)
plt.ylim([10,40])

# start data collection
i=0
while True:
        i=i+1
        ymin = float(min(ydata))-10
        ymax = float(max(ydata))+10
        plt.ylim([ymin,ymax])
        ydata.append(i)
        del ydata[0]
        line.set_xdata(np.arange(len(ydata)))
        line.set_ydata(ydata)  # update the data
        plt.draw() # update the plot
```

And it works grate when I run program step by step, but when I run it in normal mode my figure with plot freezes.